# How do you address the issue of a missing tools.jar in a JDK in Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, jakarta-ee

From my searching, I found supporting information here:  [Java Development Guide for Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/02-JavaDevTools/JavaDevTools.html)

> `tools.jar` does not exist. Classes usually located here are instead included in `classes.jar`. Scripts that rely on the existence of `tools.jar` need to be rewritten accordingly.

If a rewrite is inevitable, how does that go?

This problem was encountered while deploying on Tomcat 6 installed via MacPorts on a Mac OS X 10.6 machine.

Comment: Erwin Ramizer: a few notes... The way Java works on OS X will change soon with the new OS X release, which shall not install Java by default.  Soon Apple won't be shipping Java anymore on OS X and it's likely the new "shipper" will not be packaging Java in the same way.  OS X "server" and Mac servers are apparently getting discontinued :(

Comment: Does that mean Java developers will then have free rein on their dev environments?  By that, I mean installing the "official" packages would be the norm (like in Linux distros), instead of relying on the pre-packaged JDK/JRE.  If so, then Java dev environments would look more similar regardless of the platform, right (which, I suppose, is a good thing)?

Comment: I have no idea... I'm waiting to see how things turn out too :)

Comment: Now I don't know how to close this question.  As it turns out, the guy who asked me this no longer experiences the problem.  I asked him how it got resolved, and I haven't received a response yet.

Answer (score 8):

Here is my tested solution, which implies no change in maven config, just add symbolic links:

- ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_38-b04-436.jdk/Contents/Home/../Classes/classes.jar
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_38-b04-436.jdk/Contents/Home/../Classes/tools.jar
- ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_38-b04-436.jdk/Contents/Home/../Classes
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_38-b04-436.jdk/Contents/Home/../lib

Enjoy!
Bruno

Comment: Quick note, I had to change my JAVA_HOME to point to the /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_38-b04-436.jdk/Contents/Home/ because by default on my mountain lion machine it was pointing to /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: In my case:

`sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/lib /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/Classes
` 

and
 
`sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/Classes/classes.jar`

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to Bruno's answer above; however, I am not a big fan of symlinking the absolute path. Here is how I handle the symlinks:

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<jdk version>/Contents/Home
sudo ln -s lib Classes

cd lib/
sudo ln -s tools.jar classes.jar
```

That makes it easier then symlinking absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you search for 'tools.jar', with grep for instance. If the place where classes.jar is, where tools.jar was expected, you could just change the word.

Another idea is, to create a symbolic link from classes.jar to tools.jar, if you have enough privileges and the file system(s) on MacOS support this. Else: copy. Might be more easy, but not be forgotten for updates, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Tomcat from Macports download Tomcat from Apache.

6.0: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi

7.0: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi

Comment: I was avoiding having to install from source, which was why I chose MacPorts.  Now, I don't remember why I decided that way.  Probably because some other software was already installed via MacPorts, so I might have thought to maximize its use.

Comment: You don't have to install from source, you can download one of the binary distributions from the links above.   Just unzip and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Edit to Bruno's answer which was finally what worked for me after quite a bit of maven trial and error.

If you are using 1.7 then you should be able to change revision to 1.7. I do not know if this is still a problem in Java 1.7 though.

```
sudo sh -c '$(j_home=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6) && ln -sf ${j_home}/../Classes/classes.jar ${j_home}/../Classes/tools.jar && ln -sf ${j_home}/../Classes ${j_home}/../lib)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and resolved it differently.

- First check that the **java_home** is set as
  `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents` and not
  `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`
- Add the cobertura plugin, make sure `systemPath` is correctly ref the location of `classes.jar`

  ```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
          <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                  <version>1.6</version>
                  <scope>system</scope>
                  <systemPath>${java_home}/Classes/classes.jar</systemPath>
              </dependency>
          </dependencies>
      </plugin>
  ```
- Add the dependency and exclude tools

  ```
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
              <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Finally add the following profiles

  ```
  <profiles>
  <profile>
      <id>standard-jdk</id>
      <activation>
          <file>
              <exists>${java_home}/Home/lib/tools.jar</exists>
          </file>
      </activation>
      <properties>
          <tools-jar>${java_home}/Home/lib/tools.jar</tools-jar>
      </properties>
  </profile>
  <profile>
      <id>apple-jdk</id>
      <activation>
          <file>
              <exists>${java_home}/Classes/classes.jar</exists>
          </file>
      </activation>
      <properties>
          <tools-jar>${java_home}/Classes/classes.jar</tools-jar>
      </properties>
  </profile>
  ```

Now run maven and it should successfully generate the Cobertura reports!

Answer (score 0):

Can't find any references to it on the interweb, but my Mac 1.7 and 1.8 jdk's now have tools.jar.

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_12.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar

classes.jar is only present in mac 1.6 jdk.

--Erik

Comment: Yes, this problem was for Java 6 on Mac.