# unable to find tools.jar

Tags: java, tomcat, cobertura

I am on Mac and trying to generate Cobertura code coverage report but I am getting `Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:0` at the specified path `/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/15.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Content/Home/../lib/tools.jar`

which is similar to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616318/how-do-you-address-the-issue-of-a-missing-tools-jar-in-a-jdk-in-mac-os-x].

The weird thing is that when I go to: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.6.jdk/Contents/Home/lib`, I still cannot see `tools.jar`.

Secondly, I am not sure why the the error is showing `15.0.2` while the JVM has `11.0.6`

Comment: `tools.jar` hasn't existed for some time (JDK 9?). You appear to have multiple JDKs, which is fine, but it looks like there's some confusion about which one is actually being used.

Comment: or (the version of) Cobertura does not support Java 9 or later,  and so expects/needs `tools.jar`

Comment: @DaveNewton You are right. How can I avoid tools.jar being called? Also, interestingly I do not have cobertura plugin in my pom.xml as well.

Comment: @user15244370 I would personally like to avoid tools.jar because the `mvn cobertura:cobertura` will be running on jenkins and I do not want to go around adding it there.

Comment: I am just (trying to) saying that apparently the used version of cobertura does not run on newer version of java - use older Java version (like 8) or, maybe there is a version of cobertura that works with newer Java versions